# Manage files in the InputFile component, Blazor WASM

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-client-side

Before allowing a user to save files I want to check some file preconditions: name, size, etc. And if some file does not meet requirements then remove it from the list to save.

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <InputFile multiple OnChange="OnInputFileChange" />
</div>

@code 
{
    private async Task OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile> files = e.GetMultipleFiles(20);
        foreach (IBrowserFile imageFile in files)
        {
             if (imageFile.Size > PhotoMaxBytes)
             {
               **REMOVE FILE FROM files**
             }
            
            ...
         
        }
    }
}
```

But as I see method **GetMultipleFiles** returns **IReadOnlyList<>** and I cannot remove a file from this collection. Is there a way to do it and if not how can I clear files in the InputFile component from code? I mean if one file does not meet requirements just remove all files from InputFile. Cannot see any suitable method in the [InputFileChangeEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.inputfilechangeeventargs?view=aspnetcore-5.0).